# Capturing all changes during an application install on Windows

Tags: windows, configuration, installation, windows-installer

I need to monitor and report on all changes (folders and directories added, permissions changed, registry entries added) that are made during the installation of a software program.  Can anyone suggest a tool that is capable of doing this?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Comment: As noted in my answer below, this is a duplicate of a question on ServerFault, so I have voted to close my own question.  Let the community decide whether to keep open or not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note**: Please see my other answer below as well.

---

Seeing as you want to create a **Wix setup**, I want to add a new answer with some hints on *how to accomplish this in the quickest way*.

I would recommend using the **<del>InstallRite</del>** (no longer available) software to **get a log of changes** done by the installer you got. This tool does not allow you to convert the capture into an MSI, but it gives you a good change log (which does contain a bit of junk). The PictureTaker tool appears to have been renamed and is now [commercial](http://www.newboundary.com/products/prismpack/index.htm) - it does allow conversion of the capture to MSI though.

There seems to be a new capture tool called <del>**Scalable Smart Packager CE**</del> (link removed Nov, 2017 - target site has changed and looks a little suspicious). I have not tested this tool thoroughly.

Once you have your log or capture, you can convert to WIX in 2 "fast track" ways:

1. Use the **dark.exe** WIX MSI decompiler (if you have an MSI already)
2. Use the **heat.exe** WIX harvester tool (to auto-generate WIX XML for folders, registry etc..)

If you use the **dark.exe** tool you should get a complete WIX XML file that you can then compile again - but you should clean it up a bit (take out the UI junk, then link with WIX's detault built-in GUI etc...).

Using **heat.exe** is the cleaner way. You simply run the heat.exe tool against a folder, and it will create WIX XML elements for you to install those files. You will then need to put it all together in a WIX source files along with other required sections. I can provide you with a basic WIX "minimal sample" to get you going (I don't seem to be able to attach files here).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and comprehensive answer, Glytzkhof.  +1 and accepted as the answer.

Comment: **July 2018**: removed links to Scalable Smart Packager CE. Appears to be unmaintained.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is a duplicate of a [question answered already on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/23500/keeping-track-of-changes-to-a-system-during-software-patch-installation) (my bad!).  The answers given there are:

- [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals Software
- [Total Uninstall](http://www.martau.com/tu_download.php) from Martau.com

Answer (score 3):

> **UPDATE**: [**Stefan Kruger's comprehensive list of repackaging tools at installsite.org**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_corp.htm).

---

Your question is a bit open ended since it is not entirely clear what the **overall goal** is:

1. **Application Repackaging**: capture all changes and then package them into a deployable package format such as MSI (or similar).
2. **Reporting / Monitoring**: just looking for a way to "see what happens" during an installation.

For **application repackaging** the main tool is **[AdminStudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/application-packaging/adminstudio/)** (the main competitor "Wise InstallStudio" was pulled from market due to legal issues, see Wise section here: [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)).

[**AdminStudio**](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/) has very comprehensive feature sets and a hefty price tag (and learning curve). You could try to use the trial version to do your repackaging and see if the resulting MSI is useable. If it is not you can convert it to a Wix MSI relatively easily via the dark.exe Wix tool.

Then there used to be more **light weight tools** such as **PictureTaker** and **InstallRite** which I suppose were better suited for "reporting purposes" but could be used for MSI creation. **Both these tools seem to have disappeared as well**.

There seems to be a new capture tool called **<del>Scalable Smart Packager CE</del>** (removed broken link Jan, 2018 - the tool appears discontinued). I have not tested this tool thoroughly.

---

**UPDATE**: I just removed a broken link to Scalable Smart Packager CE (appears discontinued). For repackaging software / tools, perhaps see Stefan Kruger's comprehensive list at [**installsite.org**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_corp.htm). Hard to keep up with all these tools that are useful but end up deprecated.

---

You could use the method suggested here: [**Tracking file and registry changes**](https://serverfault.com/a/23513/20599), or you can try to locate the old version of **WININSTALL LE** on a **Windows 2000 Server CD** in `\VALUEADD\3RDPARTY\MGMT\WINSTLE`.

I believe [**Advanced Installer**](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) allows capture, but I am not sure you can export a proper MSI file with the trial version (or at all for that matter).

Comment: Glytzhzof, first off, thanks for answering, and for your comments on the question's aim. +1. I have updated the question accordingly.  I am interested in detecting and reporting on the changes that occur, in order to build my own custom application installer, using WIX.

Comment: If you follow the InstallRite link above and download InstallWatch that should do the trick for you.

Comment: It appears both PictureTaker and InstallRite are offline.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Process Monitor on multiple occasions to document the impacts of installing COTS software on servers. Has always seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a programme called "sandboxie"
You'll need to configure it once its installed for it to work properly.
run sandboxie. drag and drop the installation file into the gui and watch it try to install.
Sandboxie creates a log of everything that happens. While it redirects all of the exe - DLL - inf - scripts and everything else into a quarantine file instead.
The SB GUI then lays out the file structure to all the intended installation locations.

Any download Im not too sure is legitimate, now gets downloaded and executed straight through SB's web browser feature. I can then check it  all out and it never infects my system if it is naughty.

On the other hand...

If it was a online installer.exe that was executed in SB gui, youll now have a copy of everything that makes up the installer package. Place it all in a file on a USB, make a simple autorun.inf and .bat file with notepad++ to create ya own offline installer

Hope this helps...