# How to create own MSI package with Open Source Software?

Tags: wix, package, windows-installer, installshield, advanced-installer

does anyone know an Open Source Software for creating own MSI packages?

I wanna create an MSI file for installing a 3rd party Software. Currently it's installed via different commands (bat-file) and with different configuration files.

Is there a free Open Source software for recording an installation so that i get a MSI package as a result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***WiX** is **open source** and is one of the best way to create MSI file*. [Some other tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) (mostly commercial). Please check this answer for more information: [WiX Quick Start Suggestions and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-package-what-is-better-for-continues-delivery/25005864#25005864) (has grown too much, maybe focus on first sections - including *"Hello World & Hello WiX"*).

**The linked answer** contains links to descriptions of how WiX compares to other deployment software - both commercial and free as well as **download links** and "**get started**" recommendations.

I would recommend packaging with WiX, but if you want to capture the install as an MSI file you can check the discussion here: [Capturing all changes during an application install on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074556/capturing-all-changes-during-an-application-install-on-windows).

You might want to try **[ISWix](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix)** - a **simple GUI front end for Wix** that allows you to quickly throw together an installer by inspecting the config files and recreating the actions in Wix.

Finally you could **[download a trial version of Installshield AdminStudio](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/application-packaging/adminstudio/)** - capture your install as an MSI using the built in capture tool. Then you can **decompile** the MSI with the tool **dark.exe from Wix** and recompile it as a Wix MSI to get around any trial restrictions in the Installshield capture.

You could even use the method suggested here: [**Tracking file and registry changes**](https://serverfault.com/a/23513/20599). As this answer mentions you could try to locate the old version of **WININSTALL LE** on a **Windows 2000 Server CD** in `\VALUEADD\3RDPARTY\MGMT\WINSTLE`.

[**Advanced Installer Architect**](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) allows capture, but I am not sure you can export a proper MSI file with the trial version.

Comment: Has Wix also a capture mode, to take "snapshots" before and after manual installation?

Comment: See updates in answer.

Comment: ISWix moved from the link you provided.  Their new home page is [here](http://iswix.com/projects/), and it's hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix).

Answer (score -1):

There are several solutions, for example:

- [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/)
- [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

There is also this free one, (from comment: although it's not open sorce) also open source:

- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) Source available at [github](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc)

Comment: Actually, Inno Setup has its source available at https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc

Comment: Neither Inno Setup nor Nullsoft Scriptable Install System generate MSI files. They will only generate an EXE installer