# I have a .exe file which requires key and i want to convert it to MSI with preloaded key?

Tags: reactjs, windows-installer, exe

I have a .exe file which requires key while installation and i want to convert it to the .msi file with preloaded key ?

Comment: Are you in a big company? If so, check if there is a "Application Packaging" team or a "Software Distribution" team there. Much faster - if not there are several answers on this site on the topic. In a hurry, no links for now.

Comment: [Adapting a setup for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327442/how-to-run-an-installation-in-silent-mode-with-adjusted-settings/52338626#52338626). And I will add a couple of more links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769767/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451546/129130), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074556/capturing-all-changes-during-an-application-install-on-windows).